# Let $n = 10k + d$ where $d$ is the last digit of $n$. Show that $23|n$ if and only if $23|(2d-3k)$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is an exercise on my text book that i don't know how to prove it.

Let $n = 10k + d$ where $d$ is the last digit of $n$. Show that $23|n$ if and only if $23|(2d-3k)$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $23$ divides $10k+d$ if and only if $23$ divides $2d-3k$

**Hint:** $$2(10k+d)-(2d-3k)=23k.$$